Ubuntu 24.04 Not Printing
Epson-2200 printed perfectly with Ubuntu 22.04 but after "upgrade" to Ubuntu 24.04 it goes through the motions but only prints Network Status Sheets. I have tried various Epson drivers but they make no difference. HP DeskJet 930c still works fine. What could be the problem?

delete it then re-install the printer using add printer might fox the issue

Thank you. Have done what you suggested (Delete printer, reinstall driver, ask it to print  my 5 line address on A4) The printer appears again in Printers and prints 4 pages including my username, jobname and 4 pages of unwanted computer jargon.  It has done this a few times now and the pile of spoilt A4 grows higher, Thank you for your contribution but have you got any other possible solutions?

did you follow these instructions to reinstall the printer? Please [edit] your question with what steps you did take.

I have not followed those instructions as they seem over complicated.
I have two printers (HP Deskjet 930c and Epson XP 2200) and two operating systems (Ubuntu 22.04 and Ubuntu 24.04. Asking each operating system  to print the same test document, I find Ubuntu 22.04 will print it using either printer but Ubuntu 24.04 will only print the document using the earlier OS 22.04 This suggests a short coming in 24.04 How can this be remedied?
